# How to instantly stop a Toast on Android

Tags: android, android-toast

Is there some way to instantly kill a Toast that is displaying on Android device? I have to create a Toast with the LONG duration to show how many players are online on my game lobby. Then, after 2 players are connected, i want the toast to be destroyed immediately. I can not let the Toast appear even for a second.

Comment: Then why are you using a `Toast` in the first place? That being said, have you called `cancel()` on the `Toast`?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do something like -

```
toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10 players online", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
if(players>=2)
    toast.cancel();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but cancel() won´t instantly delete de toast. It is still appearing. I want it instantly